# How to code an intelligent coalesce in Java?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, coalesce, null-coalescing

`object.getProperty().getSubProperty().getSubSubProperty();`

Consider the code above. An object has a property, that has a subProperty, that has a subSubProperty, that can be accessed with getter methods.

What can we do in Java to achieve something like:

`Util.coalesce(object.getProperty().getSubProperty().getSubSubProperty(), defaultSubSubProperty);`

`org.apache.commons.lang3.ObjectUtils.defaultIfNull` has something like this. But the problem with this method is that it just works when property and subProperty are not null. I would like a way to get subSubProperty or defaultSubSubProperty even when property and subProperty are null.

How can we do this?

Answer (score 11):

You can use Optional in Java 8.

```
String s = Optional.ofNullable(object)
                   .map(Type::getProperty)
                   .map(Type2::getSubProperty)
                   .map(Type3::getSubSubProperty)
                   .orElse(defaultValue);
```

You can also use `orElseGet(Supplier)` or `orElseThrow(Throwable)`

Comment: Wonderfull. But I still have a problem. Here, the production Java is Java 7, can we use this in Java 7 using a jar or something like this?

Comment: @GarouDan in theory, there is backports of the library but I haven't used any.  Without the syntactic sugar I imagine using a library to be more painful than writing it yourself.

Comment: @GarouDan You can still use Guava's [`Optional`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html) (`ofNullable` -> `fromNullable`, `map` -> `transform`), but you'll have to expand all the method references to anonymous subclasses, which will make your code horribly big.